# How call a method of server when game is close

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to call a method on the server and get some data in the background ***when the game is close***. I don't know this task is possible or not .

I'm using `unity` and `C#` language .

someone told me it doesn't possible but you can write a `java` file as a library.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: How is the game communicating with the server? HTTP? Proprietary protocol? Individual calls or persistent connection?

Comment: like a get or post method.

Comment: Well in this case what you can do is keep track of when it was the last time the game communicated with the server, and make your game ping the server at least once every 20 seconds or so to keep that tracker ticking. So if you check your database that a client that was supposed to be online doesn't interact for more than 30 seconds you can just go ahead and consider it as offline. That's how I'd do it anyway.

Comment: Do you mean app is closed or minimized (was playing but then went to background) ?

Comment: when app is closed .

Comment: You have to either not close the application OR create a secondary application that only handles the updating. The 2nd approach is used from engines like STEAM where the game runs but the steam engine handles updating the game (among other things). As to what platform (java, c#, etc) you are using that is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an app while it is close, that does not make sense and would be a huge security problem. It would mean I could create an app that is running even though you don't want it (that'd be a virus then).

What you can do is get your server to run based on information you send to it. The other way is to use notifications, that would maybe get the user to start the app and you could then send the data.

There is no difference whether you would send the data while app is close or when app is reopened. So my advice, when the app gets closed or paused, send info to server. When app is reopened, ask server and do what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're are meaning getting data on the server from the client when the client disconnects (client's game closed). I haven't exactly worked with networking in Unity but in APIs and languages I'd send a disconnect packet to the server usually id'ed with a constant, the packet would contain the player's id (also could contain other stuff such as last vector positions). I would then disconnect the client on the server when receiving this packet.